# How to find N% of key and values from a python dictiobary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, percentage

I have a python dictionary:-

```
x = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4, "e": 5, "f": 6}
```

I want to find only the N% of the dictonary's keys and values returned to me.
For instance, out of this dictionary, I want to fetch 50% of the key,value pairs only.
So my output should be :-

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First calculate the count which corresponds to given percentage and also make sure it is an integer. You can also use `floor` or `ceil` functions to round of to integers. Then you can use `enumerate` as below

```
x = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4, "e": 5, "f": 6}

percent = 50

count = int(percent*len(x)/100)

output = {}
for i,key in enumerate(x.keys(),1):
    if(i>count):
        break
    output[key] = x[key]

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choice randomly N% of the element in a python dictionary, you can use `random` model.

```
import random

x = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4, "e": 5, "f": 6}

percent = 50

count = int(percent*len(x)/100)

# get list of all the keys in the  dictionary and convert it to a list
keys = x.keys()
keys = list(keys)

# use random.choices to choice randomly count element from the keys list
new_keys = random.choices(keys, k=count)

output = {}
for key in new_keys:
    output[key] = x[key]

print(output)
```

you will get as output

```
{'d': 4, 'a': 1, 'c': 3}
```